# Facing problem I want to print only Number not any other character like NaN

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

When I put Character in prompt the character is printed...

```js
var myNumber = prompt("What is your Number");
var myName = prompt("What is your name");
if (NaN != myNumber) {
  document.write("My Number is " + myNumber + " ");
} else {
  document.write("This Number is NaN ")
}
document.write("& My Name is " + myName);
```

Comment: Using `===` with `NaN` always results in false, and `!==` always results in true. If you want to check for `NaN`, you need to use `Number.isNaN(myNumber)`

Comment: `prompt()` either returns a string or `null` hence `if(NaN != myNumber)` will always be true. Also comparing anything against `NaN` does not test if "anything" is a number or can be converted into a number.

Comment: @NicholasTower There's no `===` or `!==` in the question.

Comment: @NicholasTower _"If you want to check for NaN..."_ - Which doesn't make any sense in this case

Comment: @Andreas The same is true for `==` and `!=`

Comment: @Bergi Yes but it doesn't really help (OP) to talk about something that isn't in the question...

Comment: I think the OP supposes (understandably, but incorrectly):

 1. `NaN` means "not a number"
 2. `!=` means "is not"
 3. so `x != NaN` means "x is not not a number"
 4. Therefore, x is a number.  Understandable, but the way out of the fog is to read the doc about NaN.  (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN). It is not the set of all non-number things, and `!=` and `==` are not expressions of set non-membership or membership.

Answer (score 0):

First to all i'll check if the actual `myNumber` is an actual number

```
if (!myNumber || isNaN(+myNumber)) {
   console.log("This Number is NaN ")
 } else {
   console.log("My Number is " + myNumber + " ");
 }
```

Comment: Note that the (+) before `myNumber` is very important since the `prompt` returns 
a string

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the number is a valid number, every time the user submits the prompt.

Using a while loop is also a very good idea.

```js
let myNumber = parseInt(prompt('Enter a number'));
const myName = prompt('Enter your name');

while (isNaN(myNumber)) {
    myNumber = parseInt(prompt('Please enter a valid number!'));
};

console.log(`myNumber is ${myNumber}`);
console.log(`myName is ${myName}`);
```

The while loop will continuously check to see if the input from the prompt can be converted into a number, without yielding NaN after the parseInt() function.

The string literals are just an easier way to concatenate the strings, especially when talking about using numbers and "+". It is simply a cleaner way. However both ways are possible.

Comment: Also pay attention to when the variable declaration requires you to use the parseInt() function as prompt() will always return the input as a string.

Comment: Why the `while` loop? Why the template literals?

Comment: The while loop will continuously check to see if the input from the prompt can be converted into a number, without yielding NaN after the parseInt() function.

The string literals is just an easier way to concatenate strings and commonly catches me out, especially when talking about using numbers and "+". It is simply a cleaner way. Both ways are possible.